# Trying to get a third normal form

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, uml, data-modeling

I edited the question to make it more understandable:

I got a tiny problem and I don't exactly know how to handle it.

Lets say I got a table with the following attributes and values which I want to transform into the third NF. This table is created automatically by a machine:

```
KeyID | Action | Class | Method | StoreNr. | Country

1 | Action1 | Class1 | Method1 | 123 | GB

1 | Action2 | Class2 | Method2 | 123 | GB 

2 | Action5 | Class5 | Method5 | 335 | NULL

2 | Action8 | Class8 | Method8 | 335 | NULL

3 | Action2 | Class2 | Method2 | NULL| NL

3 | Action5 | Class5 | Method5 | NULL| NL

4 | Action4 | Class4 | Method4 | NULL| NULL

4 | Action1 | Class1 | Method1 | NULL| NULL
```

As you can see the attributes KeyID, Action, Class and Method cant be NULL. StoreNr and Country CAN be NULL.

The dependencies are the following:

```
Method -> Action
Action -> Class
StoreNr -> Country
```

My problem is the KeyID. This is a randomly created number which only serves the purpose of tracking useractions. Wouldnt there be a KeyID it would be impossible to say what kind of Actions User4 used in his session.

I dont exactly know how to handle this when putting the table into the third NF.

I hope this made my needs more clear :)

Regards
Thomas

Comment: What are the functional dependencies you want to satisfy? Please list them out. There are too many unknowns here to make a reasoned guess at an answer.

Comment: Action and Class are dependend of Method. Retailer has no dependencies. The whole dataset is dependend of the KeyID.

You can imagine it like this: someone presses a buttons a webpage which triggers a method1, may be a second method will be triggered (method2). So for pressing the button ill get two datasets with KeyID one because both datasets are cohesive.

Comment: Your sample data suggests dependence between `KeyID` and `RetailerNr`. Is that just a coincidence?

Comment: @User "The whole dataset is dependend [sic] of the KeyID". Your example data seems to contradict you. KeyID is *not* a determinant for all the other attributes.

Comment: Retailer can be any given number, there is no dependency between retailer and keyid

Comment: BTW, a whole row cannot be functionally dependent on `KeyId` - there are two different rows for the same value of `KeyID`. I don't know if that's what you meant by _"The whole dataset is dependend of the KeyID"_?

Comment: @user Your answers are contradictory. Please edit your question and list out ALL the dependencies in the form A->B where A and B are sets of attributes.

Comment: @ sqlvogel, well no... its a bit hard for me to explain :(. the KeyID basicly links two datasets which belong together.

Comment: Could you please list these "datasets" or otherwise explain what they mean?

Comment: I think it is very easy to explain, if you list out the FDs in the usual way.

Comment: i updated the question above, hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your stated set of dependencies

```
Method -> Action
Action -> Class
StoreNr -> Country
```

and your sample data suggests at least 6 relations, as follows. Depending on what you intended by the nulls in your sample data this may be simpler than you are making it. Nulls do not need to be part of any properly stated business requirement or FD - they are merely a technical feature of the implementation you have created.

```
R1 {Method,Action} KEY {Method}
R2 {Action,Class} KEY {Action}
R3 {StoreNr,Country} KEY {StoreNr}
R4 {Method,KeyId} KEY {Method,KeyId}
R5 {Method,KeyId,Country} KEY {Method,KeyId}
R6 {Method,KeyId,StoreNr} KEY {Method,KeyId}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third normal form essentially means that data should be stored at its natural level. So, if you have a table of employees you should include the salary of that employee and the department they are a member of but not the average salary of the department because that is department "level" information.

> Action and Class are dependend of Method. Retailer has no
>   dependencies. The whole dataset is dependend of the KeyID.

If Action and Class are dependent on Method you need a table that is unique on Method. You say your problem is the KeyID, but this seems to need a foreign key in the Method table. I don't know if there is any additional data you would store at this level or not. Retailer seems to be part of Action and Class from your sample data; it can't be completely independent or it has no business being in the same dataset.

Assuming the above is correct you would want tables as follows:

```
Keys
    KeyID - PK
    ????

Methods
    MethodID - PK
    Class
    Action
    KeyID - FK to Keys

Retailers
    RetailerNR - PK
    ???
```

This may be slightly incorrect as your question is a little confused but you know your own data best; store data at it's natural level and you can't fail to put it into 3NF.